# How to set callback function in fancyProductDesigner function using fabric js

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs, js-fancyproductdesigner

I am create canvas using `fabric js`.
I am not able to track, when canvas is fully load.
I am using `fancyProductDesigner` function. Please help me out to call function when canvas load.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'when canvas is fully load'? Are you talking about dom load?

Comment: Please create a snippet or bin so it will be much easier for us to understand you.

Answer (score 0):

The FancyProductDesigner.js supplies necessary data to productdesigner.php , which located in templates. Custom jQuery triggers were used to load canvas .  Checkout the constructor of FancyProductDesigner.js